# Thymeleaf hide tag wen th:text="#{var}"

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi I'm trying to hide tags wen the message is empty but I can't seem to figure out how, for what I read if I want to hide and empty variable all I need to do is either with "unless" or "if":

```
 <p th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(myVar.theEmptyVar)}">
```

But when I use the message type var It doesn't seem to work the code fails

```
<p th:unless=""{#strings.isEmpty(messageVar)}">
```

The closest I got is this but it won't show anything:

```
<p th:if="${!#strings.isEmpty('[[#{label}]]')}" >
```

I've been going up and down the thymeleaf documentation and google but I can't seem to find a solution that works, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better your case? Why do you change always the variable name inside the example? Can you write the myVar structure?

Comment: Hi I was using them as case examples, sorry for the mix up, basically I have this code:

<p th:text="#{var}" ></p>

and I want to hide it wen the var is empty, I was thinking using an "if" or unless, but wen I use:

<p th:if="#{label}" > 
 the code breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `label`, which is an empty entry in a messages file, like this:

```
label=
```

...then you can use the following in your Thymeleaf template:

```
<p th:if=" ! ${#strings.isEmpty(#messages.msg('label'))}">
     my text     
</p>
```

The `!` is a negation ("not"). Therefore, because the message for `label` is empty, you will *not* see "my text" in the web page, and the `<p>` tag will *not* be created.

If you remove the `!` then you *will* see "my text", inside the `<p>` tag.

You cannot use `#{label}` directly in this specific case. You have to wrap it in the `#messages.msg()` method.

Also, if the `label` message does not exist in the message file, then this will behave the same way as `label=`.

Comment: Another way you could go about this: `<th:block th:with="var=#{var}"><p th:unless="${#strings.isEmpty(var)}" th:text="${var}" /></th:block>`